# showPageLoadingMsg not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My function to get a spinner to load on page load does not seem to be working.

```
$('#HomeViewPage_ColleagueLocation').live('pagebeforeshow', function(toPage, fromPage){
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "No spinner", true);
            setTimeout("test()", 2000);

            GetAllUsersByTeam();
            GetAvailableTeams();
            $('#colleagueLocationLabel').text(CurrentLocationName);
    });

function test(){
        alert("works");
    }
```

The page loads fine, and the alert goes off, but i never see the "No spinner" message.
BTW I am using IE9.
Why isnt this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing:

```
$('#HomeViewPage_ColleagueLocation').live('pagebeforeshow', function(toPage, fromPage)
```

to:

```
$('#HomeViewPage_ColleagueLocation').live('pageshow', function(toPage, fromPage)
```

solved it.